# Counts and average code

Tags: statistics, awk

Using the columns 4 and 2 will create a report like the output file showed below. My code works fine but I believe it can be done shorter.

I have a doubt in the part of the split:

```
CNTLM = split ("20,30,40,60", LMT
```

It works but will be better to have exactly the values "10,20,30,40" as values in column 4:

> ```
> 4052538693,2910,04-May-2018-22,10
> 4052538705,2910,04-May-2018-22,10
> 4052538717,2910,04-May-2018-22,10
> 4052538729,2911,04-May-2018-22,20
> 4052538741,2911,04-May-2018-22,20
> 4052538753,2912,04-May-2018-22,20
> 4052538765,2912,04-May-2018-22,20
> 4052538777,2914,04-May-2018-22,10
> 4052538789,2914,04-May-2018-22,10
> 4052538801,2914,04-May-2018-22,30
> 4052539029,2914,04-May-2018-22,20
> 4052539041,2914,04-May-2018-22,20
> 4052539509,2915,04-May-2018-22,30
> 4052539521,2915,04-May-2018-22,30
> 4052539665,2915,04-May-2018-22,30
> 4052539677,2915,04-May-2018-22,10
> 4052539689,2915,04-May-2018-22,10
> 4052539701,2916,04-May-2018-22,40
> 4052539713,2916,04-May-2018-22,40
> 4052539725,2916,04-May-2018-22,40
> 4052539737,2916,04-May-2018-22,40
> 4052539749,2916,04-May-2018-22,40
> 4052539761,2917,04-May-2018-22,10
> 4052539773,2917,04-May-2018-22,10
> ```

Here is the code I use to get the output desired:

```awk
printf " Code       10       20       30       40      Total\n"  > header
dd=`cat header | wc -L` 


awk -F"," '
BEGIN   {CNTLM = split ("20,30,40,60", LMT)
         cmdsort = "sort -nr"
         DASHES = sprintf ("%0*d", '$dd', _)
         gsub (/0/, "-", DASHES)
        }

        {for (IX=1; IX<=CNTLM; IX++) if ($4 <= LMT[IX]) break
         CNT[$2,IX]++ 
         COLTOT[IX]++
         LNC[$2]++
         TOT++
         }

END     {
     print DASHES

         for (l in LNC)
                {printf "%5d", l | cmdsort
                 for (IX=1; IX<=CNTLM; IX++)  {printf "%9d", CNT[l,IX]+0   | cmdsort
                                                }
                 printf "  = %6d" RS, LNC[l] | cmdsort
                }
         close (cmdsort)

         print DASHES
         printf "Total"
         for (IX=1; IX<=CNTLM; IX++) printf "%9d", COLTOT[IX]+0
         printf "  = %6d" RS, TOT
         print DASHES

         printf "PCT  "
         for (IX=1; IX<=CNTLM; IX++) printf "%9.1f", COLTOT[IX]/TOT*100
         printf RS
     print DASHES

        }
'  file 

cat header output
```

Output file I got:

> ```
> Code       10       20       30       40      Total
> ----------------------------------------------------
>  2917        2        0        0        0  =      2
>  2916        0        0        0        5  =      5
>  2915        2        0        3        0  =      5
>  2914        2        2        1        0  =      5
>  2912        0        2        0        0  =      2
>  2911        0        2        0        0  =      2
>  2910        3        0        0        0  =      3
> ----------------------------------------------------
> Total        9        6        4        5  =     24
> ----------------------------------------------------
> PCT       37.5     25.0     16.7     20.8
> ----------------------------------------------------
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not very much different from your solution. It does not rely on the header being hardcoded though. Depends on GNU awk for the use of [PROCINFO to control array traversal](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html#Controlling-Scanning).

```
gawk -F, '
    {count[$2,$4]++; code[$2]; val[$4]}
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
        printf "Code\t"
        dashes = "--------"
        for (v in val) {
            printf "%8d", v
            dashes = dashes "--------"
        }
        printf " =%8s\n", "Total"
        dashes = dashes "-----------"
        print dashes

        for (c in code) {
            sum_code = 0
            printf "%d\t", c
            for (v in val) {
                sum_code += count[c,v]
                sum_val[v] += count[c,v]
                printf "%8d", count[c,v]
            }
            printf " =%8d\n", sum_code
        }
        print dashes

        printf "Total\t"
        sum = 0
        for (v in val) {
            sum += sum_val[v]
            printf "%8d", sum_val[v]
        }
        printf " =%8d\n", sum
        print dashes

        printf "PCT\t"
        for (v in val) {
            printf "%8.1f", 100*sum_val[v]/sum
        }
        print "\n" dashes
    }
' file
```

```
Code          10      20      30      40 =   Total
---------------------------------------------------
2910           3       0       0       0 =       3
2911           0       2       0       0 =       2
2912           0       2       0       0 =       2
2914           2       2       1       0 =       5
2915           2       0       3       0 =       5
2916           0       0       0       5 =       5
2917           2       0       0       0 =       2
---------------------------------------------------
Total          9       6       4       5 =      24
---------------------------------------------------
PCT         37.5    25.0    16.7    20.8
---------------------------------------------------
```

I'm not a fan of ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES

Comment: Glenn.. your code version works perfectly. appreciate the modification done